# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How to add a record to a Queue (QueueItem) using the REST Endpoint with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, rest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to assign record to a particular queue in my Silverlight application.

I display a list of record, and the user can select one or many record. Then I display a list of queue, and the user select the Queue in which he want to add those records.

I've followed this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309558.aspx

I've tried different way but it never worked.

First,

I've tried to create an "empty" QueueItem: (some parts of the code are missing, for example there is no Queue record here but it's not important, it's just to show you the issue)

```
internal void AddBillingToQueue()
    {
        QueueItem item = new QueueItem();

        context.AddToQueueItemSet(item);

        context.BeginSaveChanges(OnCreateCompleted, item);
    }

    private void OnCreateCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        QueueItem item = result.AsyncState as QueueItem
        DataServiceResponse response = context.EndSaveChanges(result);

        // Normally, the GUID shouldn't be empty anymore, 
        // but it fails at the EndSaveChanges line.
    }
```

The exception message said the objecttypecode was missing. So I tried again providing the object that I want to put in the queue.

```
internal void AddBillingToQueue(all_billing billing)
    {
        QueueItem item = new QueueItem();
        item.ObjectId = new EntityReference()
        {
            Name = billing.all_name,
            Id = billing.all_billingId,
            LogicalName = "all_billing"
        }

        context.AddToQueueItemSet(item);

        context.BeginSaveChanges(OnCreateCompleted, item);
    }

    private void OnCreateCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        QueueItem item = result.AsyncState as QueueItem
        DataServiceResponse response = context.EndSaveChanges(result);

        // again it fails
    }
```

The exception message now says that the QueueId is missing. So I tried providing also the reference to the Queue.

```
internal void AddBillingToQueue(all_billing billing, Queue queue)
    {
        QueueItem item = new QueueItem();

        item.ObjectId = new EntityReference()
        {
            Name = billing.all_name,
            Id = billing.all_billingId,
            LogicalName = "all_billing"
        }


        item.QueueId = new EntityReference()
        {
            Name = queue.Name,
            Id = queue.QueueId,
            LogicalName = "Queue"
        };

        context.AddToQueueItemSet(item);

        context.BeginSaveChanges(OnCreateCompleted, item);
    }

    private void OnCreateCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        QueueItem item = result.AsyncState as QueueItem
        DataServiceResponse response = context.EndSaveChanges(result);

        // again it fails
    }
```

And here, the exception message is this one:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\">
<code>-2147217150</code>
<message xml:lang=\"nl-BE\">Queue</message>
</error>
```

According to this site ( http://www.cub-e.net/post/Microosft-Dynamics-CRM-Error-Code-List.aspx ), the code means: *The specified entity was not found.* I suppose it means that Queue hasn't been found.

But the GUID provided is definitely right because it has been retrieved from the same context.

So, if I provide the Queue Id, it fails. And if I don't, it fails to. What have I missed? Does someone have already work with QueueItem and REST endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be pointing out the obvious, you did mention that not all the code is there so I did wonder if this is a side effect of that but the line.

```
LogicalName = "Queue"
```

Jumped out at me as using the rest endpoint is case sensitive as far as the entity name is concerned (ie all lowercase) so it may not be able to find the queue due to this.

Apart from that, if your application is showing queues to the user for assigning items this point may also be a mute but if it's the actual record it cannot find make sure there are permissions to be able to see the queue, add to the queue / assign the item your attempting to put into the queue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried so many times! How is it possible that I've missed it? Of course it should be lowercase :) Thanks for pointing that out!